# Is it possible for an array to know its parent?

Tags: php

Consider this array:

```
$super = [
  "first"  => ["first1","first2"],
  "second" => ["second1","second2"]
];
```

Now let's grab a reference to the subarray:

```
$sub = $super["second"];
```

How can I reference the super array from the sub array?

I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
var_dump($sub[../"first"]);
```

> array (size=2)
>     0 => string 'first1' (length=6)
>     1 => string 'first2' (length=6)

Comment: No. Not possible. PHP arrays have linkages only going "down" the tree, never up. a child array has NO idea what its parent is. it's the parents' responsibility to keep track of that.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, that's what I suspected.

Comment: I think that link would helpfull http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you tell us what you're actually trying to do instead of asking about this code implementation detail ?

Comment: @naomik thanks for asking. it's a complex problem, so I'll ping you when I can break it down to an MVCE if I'm still unable to figure it out on my own. I thought this might be a feasible solution, and was curious if it was even possible on its own merit.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII for sure. I'm intrigued. Keep me in the loop.

Comment: @naomik if you're still interested, [here's my real problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39260573/4233593).

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thanks, I'll take a look at it tonight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/language.types.array) are implemented as ordered hashmaps. Which means that every **key** in the array gets hashed and maps directly to a **value**. That value could be another *array*, sure, but the map does not go in reverse. So a value cannot map back to a key in PHP or in the implementation of any typical hashmap. The hash only goes *one way*.

So in `$arr = ["foo" => ["bar"]]` the key `"foo"` in the array `$arr` will map to the value `["bar"]`, which happens to be another array. But there is no way to go in reverse order (i.e. map the value `["bar"]` back to the key `"foo"` in `$arr`).

If you want this kind of *co-recursive* relationship, like a tree or graph, it's actually easier to accomplish with objects, because objects don't have the same by copy-by-value semantics that arrays do.

```
$obj = new stdClass;


$obj->first  = new stdClass;
$obj->second = new stdClass;

$obj->first->parent = $obj;
$obj->second->parent = $obj;

$obj->first->value = ["first1", "first2"];
$obj->second->value= ["second1","second2"];

$first = $obj->first; // now I can ask it for its parent
$second = $first->parent->second->value;
var_dump($second);
```

You get

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "second1"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "second2"
}
```

Now it doesn't actually matter if you change the value from `$first` or `$obj`. The object remains intact, because PHP objects aren't stored directly in the variable. They are stored in a container that's abstracted away from userland and the variable merely holds a reference to this container. So `$first` and `$obj` still both point to the same object.

So continuing from the example above, if we tried something like this ...

```
$second = $first->parent->second;

$first->parent->second->value = ["I changed you!", "I changed you too!"];

// This magically gets the right value
var_dump($second->value, $obj->second->value);
```

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "I changed you!"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "I changed you too!"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "I changed you!"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "I changed you too!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice alternative approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can only know what's the parent index of an index by creating custom function like this :

```
function get_parent($key, $arr){
    $index = 0;
    foreach($arr as $keyCur => $val){
        if($keyCur === $key){
            $ret = [];
            $ret['indexOfKey'] = $index;
            $ret['valueOfKey'] = $val;
            return $ret;
        }
        $index++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: could you please demonstrate with the example I have provided in the question?

Comment: You can easily find what's the parent key of "second" named key like this :
$key = get_parent('second', $super);

Comment: If This finds any match, it will return an array of contains indexOfKey and valueOfKey elements in it, if it doesn't it will return false.