# How to get count of distinct XML nodes?

Tags: php, xml

I'm having trouble using references in recursive calls.

What I am trying to accomplish is to describe an XML document in terms of the max count of distinct nodes within a respective element - without knowing any of the node element names in advance.

Consider this document:

```
<Data>
    <Record>
        <SAMPLE>
            <TITLE>Superior Title</TITLE>
            <SUBTITLE>Sub Title</SUBTITLE>
            <AUTH>
                <FNAME>John</FNAME>
                <DISPLAY>No</DISPLAY>
            </AUTH>
            <AUTH>
                <FNAME>Jane</FNAME>
                <DISPLAY>No</DISPLAY>
            </AUTH>
            <ABSTRACT/>
        </SAMPLE>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <SAMPLE>
            <TITLE>Interesting Title</TITLE>
            <AUTH>
                <FNAME>John</FNAME>
                <DISPLAY>No</DISPLAY>
            </AUTH>
            <ABSTRACT/>
        </SAMPLE>
        <SAMPLE>
            <TITLE>Another Title</TITLE>
            <AUTH>
                <FNAME>Jane</FNAME>
                <DISPLAY>No</DISPLAY>
            </AUTH>
            <ABSTRACT/>
        </SAMPLE>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

You can see that a `Record` has either 1 or 2 `SAMPLE` nodes and that the `SAMPLE` has 1 or 2 `AUTH` nodes. I'm trying to produce an array that will describe the structure of the document in terms of the max number of distinct nodes inside a respective node.

So I'm trying to get a result like this:

```
$result = [

  "Data" => [
    "max_count" => 1,
    "elements" => [

      "Record" => [
        "max_count" => 2,
        "elements" => [

          "SAMPLE" => [
            "max_count" => 2,
            "elements" => [

              "TITLE" => [
                "max_count" => 1
              ],
              "SUBTITLE" => [
                "max_count" => 1
              ],
              "AUTH" => [
                "max_count" => 2,
                "elements" => [

                  "FNAME" => [
                    "max_count" => 1
                  ],
                  "DISPLAY" => [
                    "max_count" => 1
                  ]

                ]
              ],
              "ABSTRACT" => [
                "max_count" => 1
              ]

            ]
          ]

        ]
      ]

    ]
  ]

];
```

To preserve a little bit of my sanity, I'm using [sabre/xml](http://sabre.io/xml/reading/) to do the legwork parsing the XML.

I can get an absolute count of elements using recursive calls with a reference to the original array.

```
  private function countArrayElements(&$array, &$result){
    // get collection of subnodes
    foreach ($array as $node){

      $name = $this->stripNamespace($node['name']);

      // get count of distinct subnodes
      if (empty($result[$name])){
        $result[$name]["max_count"] = 1;
      } else {
        $result[$name]["max_count"]++;
      }

      if (is_array($node['value'])){
        $this->countArrayElements($node['value'], $result[$name]["elements"]);
      }

    }
  }
```

So my reasoning was that I could also pass the array by reference and do a comparison, which works for the top two nodes, but somehow resets on the subsequent nodes which results in a count of only 1 for the `AUTH` node.

```
  private function countArrayElements(&$array, &$previous){

    // get collection of subnodes
    foreach ($array as $node){

      $name = $this->stripNamespace($node['name']);

      // get count of distinct subnodes
      if (empty($result[$name]["max_count"])){
        $result[$name]["max_count"] = 1;
      } else {
        $result[$name]["max_count"]++;
      }

      // recurse
      if (is_array($node['value'])){
        $result[$name]["elements"] = $this->countArrayElements(
          $node['value'],
          $result[$name]["elements"]
        );
      }

      // compare previous max
      if (!empty($previous[$name]["max_count"])){
        $result[$name]["max_count"] = max(
          $previous[$name]["max_count"],
          $result[$name]["max_count"]
        );
      }

    }

    return $result;

  }
```

I realize this is a pretty complex question, of which it is just a small piece of a much larger project, so I have tried to break it down as much as possible for this MCVE and I have additionally prepared [a special repository](https://github.com/admonkey/describer) of these files complete with a phpunit test.

Comment: The problem with your structure is what happens if the second `<SAMPLE>` node contains `<SUBTITLE>` node that's not in the first one. Your way, you make it look like there is a single `<RECORD>` node that contains two `<SAMPLE>` nodes. So it's not actually backwards compatible with XML at all.

Comment: @Sherif the code currently handles missing nodes correctly. If one `SAMPLE` contains a single `SUBTITLE` node and it's not in any other `SAMPLE` node, then the describe function will report `max_count = 1`

Comment: @Sherif I have updated the question and repository with the missing `SUBTITLE` node example. curiously, it doesn't work with the reference issue that I'm currently facing, but works as expected with the absolute count.

Comment: That's not true. It just happens to work out in that particular example because you put the `SUBTITLE` node in the ***first*** `SAMPLE` node and ***not*** in the second one like my comment states. The reason I'm questioning the entire approach is to establish the correctness of the solution. I just don't understand your definition of `max_count`. What exactly does the `max_count` mean for `DATA`, for example? That the entire XML document contains at _most_ 2 `DATA` nodes? Or that its parent element contains at _most_ two child nodes of `DATA`? It's ambiguous.

Comment: @Sherif because `DATA` is the root node, it's taken for granted that it is always `max_count = 1`

Comment: OK, reaplace `Data` with `<any node other than the root node>`.

Comment: @Sherif I apologize that I'm not very good at explaining myself. To test, I have changed the position of the `SUBTITLE` node and placed it in the middle of the document and it still passes. You can checkout [the updated repository](https://github.com/admonkey/describer) if you're interested in seeing for yourself.

Comment: Alright, so I've reviewed your repository and your code does actually work and is correct. I just misunderstood your requirements. I've updated my answer as an alternative solution to the problem, but I'm actually upvoting your answer as it was the correct one specific to this question. My answer is only a more generalized one to work with any DOM tree, and not just specifically XML. So hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your solution works, and pretty efficiently given that it operates in `O(n*k)` time (*where `n` is the number of nodes in the tree and `k` is the number of vertices*), I figured I'd propose an alternative solution that doesn't rely on arrays or references and is more generalized to work, not just for XML, but for any DOM tree. This solution also operates in `O(n*k)` time, so it's just as efficient. The only difference is you can consume the values from a [generator](http://php.net/generators) without having to build out the entire array first.

## Modeling The Problem

The easiest way for me to understand this problem is to model it as a graph. If we model the document that way what we get are levels and vertices.

[image: DOM tree figure1]

So effectively, this allows us to divide and conquer, breaking down the problem into two distinct steps.

1. Count the cardinal child node names of a given vertical as the `sum` (*verticies*)
2. Find the `max` of the collective `sum` on the horizontal (*levels*)

Which means that if we do level-order traversal on this tree we should be able to easily produce the cardinality of node names as the maximum sum of all the verticals.

[image: DOM tree figure2]

In other words, there's a cardinality problem of getting the distinct child node names of each node. Then there's the issue of finding the maximum sum for that entire level.

## Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Self-Contained Example

So to provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, and Self-Contained Example I'm going to rely on extending PHP's `DOMDocument` rather than the third party XML library you're using in your example.

> It's probably worth noting that this code is not backwards compatible with PHP 5, (because of the use of `yield from`), so you **must** use PHP 7 for this implementation to work.

First, I'm going to implement a function in `DOMDocument` that allows us to iterate over the DOM tree in level-order by using a [generator](http://php.net/generators).

```
class SpecialDOM extends DOMDocument {
    public function level(DOMNode $node = null, $level = 0, $ignore = ["#text"]) {
        if (!$node) {
            $node = $this;
        }
        $stack = [];
        if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
            foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
                if (!in_array($child->nodeName, $ignore, true)) {
                    $stack[] = $child;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($stack) {
            yield $level => $stack;
            foreach($stack as $node) {
                yield from $this->level($node, $level + 1, $ignore);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The mechanics of the function itself is actually quite simple. It doesn't rely on passing around arrays or using references, but instead uses the `DOMDocument` object itself, to build a stack of all child nodes in a given node. Then it can `yield` this entire stack at once. This is the *level* part. At which point we rely on recursion to yield from each element in this stack any other nodes on the *next* level.

Here's a very simple XML document to demonstrate how straight-forward this is.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Data>
    <Record>
        <SAMPLE>Some Sample</SAMPLE>
    </Record>
    <Note>
        <SAMPLE>Some Sample</SAMPLE>
    </Note>
    <Record>
        <SAMPLE>Sample 1</SAMPLE>
        <SAMPLE>Sample 2</SAMPLE>
    </Record>
</Data>
XML;

$dom = new SpecialDOM;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

foreach($dom->level() as $level => $stack) {
    echo "- Level $level\n";
    foreach($stack as $item => $node) {
        echo "$item => $node->nodeName\n";
    }
}
```

The output will look like this.

```
- Level 0
0 => Data
- Level 1
0 => Record
1 => Note
2 => Record
- Level 2
0 => SAMPLE
- Level 2
0 => SAMPLE
- Level 2
0 => SAMPLE
1 => SAMPLE
```

So at least now we have a way of knowing what level a node is on and in what order it appears on that level, which is useful for what we intend to do.

Now the idea of building a nested array is actually unnecessary to obtain the cardinality sought by `max_count`. Because we already have access to the nodes themselves from the DOM tree. Which means we know what `elements` are contained therein inside of our loop at each iteration. We don't have to generate the entire array at once to begin exploring it. We can do this at a level-order instead, which is actually really cool, because it means you can build a flat array to get to `max_count` for each record.

Let me demonstrate how that would work.

```
$max = [];
foreach($dom->level() as $level => $stack) {
    $sum = [];
    foreach($stack as $item => $node) {
        $name = $node->nodeName;
        // the sum
        if (!isset($sum[$name])) {
            $sum[$name] = 1;
        } else {
            $sum[$name]++;
        }
        // the maximum
        if (!isset($max[$level][$name])) {
            $max[$level][$name] = 1;
        } else {
            $max[$level][$name] = max($sum[$name], $max[$level][$name]);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($max);
```

The output we get would look like this.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Data"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Record"]=>
    int(2)
    ["Note"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["SAMPLE"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Which proves that we can calculate `max_count` without the need for references or complex nested arrays. It's also easier to wrap your head around when you obviate the *one-way* mapping semantics of PHP arrays.

## Synopsis

Here's the resulting output from this code on your sample XML document.

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Data"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Record"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["SAMPLE"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["TITLE"]=>
    int(1)
    ["SUBTITLE"]=>
    int(1)
    ["AUTH"]=>
    int(2)
    ["ABSTRACT"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["FNAME"]=>
    int(1)
    ["DISPLAY"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Which is identical to the `max_count` of each of your sub arrays.

- Level 0

  - `Data => max_count 1`
- Level 1

  - `Record => max_count 2`
- Level 2

  - `SAMPLE => max_count 2`
- Level 3

  - `TITLE => max_count 1`
  - `SUBTITLE => max_count 1`
  - `AUTH => max_count 2`
  - `ABSTRACT => max_count 1`
- LEVEL 4

  - `FNAME => max_count 1`
  - `DISPLAY => max_count 1`

To get the elements for any of these nodes throughout the loop just look at `$node->childNodes` as you already have the tree (*thus eliminating the need for references*).

The only reason you needed to nest the elements into your array is because the keys of a PHP array have to be unique and since you're using the node name as the key this requires nesting to get the lower levels of the tree and still structure the value of `max_count` properly. So it's a data structure problem there and I solve it differently by avoiding modeling the solution after the data structure.

Comment: Good answer, but two suggestions: The `TITLE` element count can be fetched directly with `$xpath->evaluate('count(//TITLE)')`. While `count($node->childNodes)` includes text nodes, comments, ... it is possible to use Xpath with conditions, too: `$elementCount = $xpath->evaluate('count(*)', $node)`.

Comment: Hi firstly thanks for pointing out that [references are not pointers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php) - I have corrected my question. Secondly, your approach is vastly different but I will try to adapt it to my needs today or tomorrow and will get back to you. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: After taking a deeper look into your answer, I have a few issues applying it to my conceptual goals - and this is probably my fault for poorly explaining the problem. The first part of your answer reproduces the document without any distinct grouping, which isn't clear to me how it's useful - I can parse the document just fine and get this same information. The second part of your answer seems to depend on XPath queries and an existing knowledge of the element tag names which isn't available. As I alluded in my question, this is a small piece of a greater application intended to describe this.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand about your question is the ambiguity of _distinct grouping_ and `max_count`. If something is _distinct_ it cannot have a minimum and a maximum. It is seen as just one thing. Which is why your example would make no sense when there are `RECORD` nodes and you portray them as a _single_ thing. Because what if one `RECORD` node has another `RECORD` node. Does that count towards the max? Do its child nodes count towards the max of other nodes of the same name? How does that relationship work?

Comment: Hi I really hope I'm not annoying you with my inabilities to precisely articulate my intentions. By *distinct grouping*, which is surely an incorrect term, I am trying to get at counting the number of nodes with respect to a parent's peer. So one node has `x` number of `a` nodes, to whereas a peer node of the same name might have `y` number of `a` nodes. I'm just trying to figure out of what's the max count of `a` nodes in any given parent node. Ugh, sorry I suck at explaining because re-reading this doesn't even make sense to me. I should have majored in English LOL

Comment: No, you're not annoying me at all. I'm actually quite interested in the problem, which is why I'm trying to clarify and get a better understanding of what you need. But actually that clears it up quite nicely. One moment while I update my answer to re-articulate :)

Comment: Wow! I'm accepting your answer because 1) it's amazing and 2) it's generalized and more valuable to future readers than my answer. Your diagrams are powerful! What did you use to make them?

Comment: One clarification I see for my super-project (*not* in the current question) is that Level 3 would have 2 different nodes of the same name "Sample" because they belong to different named parents ("Record" and "Note"). So `Data/Record/Sample` would be `max_count = 2` and `Data/Note/Sample` would be `max_count = 1` I've updated the repo with a `DIFFERENT` node containing a `TITLE` node like in the `SAMPLE` node. This is why it's important to me to preserve the structure. The only way you could have possible gleaned that was from my subtle comment "...to whereas a peer node *of the same name*..."

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear on your last comment "_it's important to me to preserve the structure_". The structure of the DOM tree is preserved in the DOM document object. We never change that.

Comment: According to your orange diagram, you count 2 distinct nodes `Sample` and `Line` but for my purposes I would need to count that as 3 distinct nodes `Sample`, `Sample`, and `Line` because `Note/Sample` is distinct from `Record/Sample` Btw, if you didn't see my previous comment, what do you use to make these diagrams? Also, because the first comment is from someone else, I'm not getting pinged when you comment - I am just checking back manually. Please ping me with @Jeff if you want to insure I see your message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122550/discussion-between-sherif-and-jeff-puckett-ii).

Answer (score 3):

I feel so foolish for not realizing how easy the solution is to simply store a local variable in the function call that compares the existing value passed by reference.

```
  private function countArrayElements(&$array, &$result){

    // use local variable for temp storage
    $local_count = [];

    // get collection of subnodes
    foreach ($array as $node){

      $name = $this->stripNamespace($node['name']);

      // get count of distinct subnodes
      if (empty($local_count[$name]["max_count"])){
        $local_count[$name]["max_count"] = 1;
      } else {
        $local_count[$name]["max_count"]++;
      }

      // compare local to passed reference for max
      if(empty($result[$name]["max_count"])){
        $result[$name]["max_count"] = $local_count[$name]["max_count"];
      } else {
        $result[$name]["max_count"] = max(
          $local_count[$name]["max_count"],
          $result[$name]["max_count"]
        );
      }

      if (is_array($node['value'])){
        $this->countArrayElements($node['value'], $result[$name]["elements"]);
      }

    }
  }
```